# Universal approximation of probability distribution with latent variable model

Tags: sampling, approximation, latent-variable

I want to show that under certain circumstances this form can approximate any probability distribution. For that, I came up with the following argument.

Consider a directed graphical model of the form $\int p(x|z)p(z)dz, z \in \mathbb{R}^n, x \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

$p(z)$ is an arbitrary prior, such as a multivariate Gaussian. Let $p(x|z)$ be a Dirac distribution, i.e. $p(x=f(z)|z) = \infty$ and $p(x\neq f(z)|z) = 0$ implemented by a map $f$.

**Proposition:** $p(x) = \int p(x|z)p(z)dz$ if $f=h \circ g$ with $g$ the CDF of $p(z)$ and $h$ the inverse CDF of $p(x)$.

**Proof:** Sampling from $p(z)$ and applying its CDF will yield samples from the uniform distribution. Applying the inverse CDF of $p(x)$ to the uniform distribution will yield samples from $p(x)$. Since distributions yielding the same samples have equivalent CDFs the proposition follows.

My questions now are:

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. If so, has this argument been made in the literature before? Is there any standard result I can cite?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to prove here? You've just shown the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), but what does it prove? Moreover, there's no approximation anywhere, so it's not clear what you want to approximate.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your proposition.  But can't we always take $p(x|z) = p(x)$ (thus independence of $X$ and $Z$) and it would certainly be true that
\begin{align*}
\int p(x|z) p(z) dz &= \int p(x) p(z) dz \\
&= p(x),
\end{align*}
for any distributions $p(x)$ and $p(z)$?

Moreover, many other choices of $p(x|z)$ will serve, in fact, you can take $p(x|z)$ to be any copula. There are an infinity of joint distributions that give rise to the marginals $p(x), p(z)$.